# Existence of Taylor-like expansion in perturbation parameter

Tags: mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory, online-resources

In perturbation theory, we assume that a Taylor-like series exists in the perturbation parameter. But is this always true? Or are there certain conditions? Also, can I get some resource recommendations where I can read more about the theory of perturbation theory? Theory as in a rigorous explanation of why it works, not the different kinds of perturbative approaches.

Comment: [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)

Comment: @user10354138 I don't quite follow. What does implicit function theorem have to do with this?

Comment: nevermind, I think I got it

Comment: [Kato, Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf).